# RC522 default key

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, rfid

I have a problem with authenticate my mifare card. In datasheet is written that default key is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFF` but it doesn't work. I don't have any idea what is wrong, if someone could help me.

Here is my code and I want to add that checking card is correct and works fine.

main.c:

```
    #include "spi.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "oldrc522.h"


    int main(void) {

    uint8_t CARD_ID[5];

    uint8_t KEY[6]={0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};
    uint8_t MY_CARD[5]={0x19,0x5a,0xcc,0xac,0x23};

    TM_MFRC522_Init();
    printf("INIT\n\n\n");

    while(1){

    if (TM_MFRC522_Check(CARD_ID) == MI_OK) {
                //CardID is valid

                //Check if this is my card
                if (TM_MFRC522_Compare(CARD_ID, MY_CARD) == MI_OK) {
                   printf("HELLO!\n\n");

                   if( (TM_MFRC522_Auth(PICC_AUTHENT1A,7,KEY,MY_CARD) == MI_OK))
                       printf("OK");
                   else printf("FAILED\n\n");



                } else
                    printf("INVALID CARD\n\n");


            } else {
                //Some printing to delete content
            }

    }
}
```

TM_MFRC522_Auth function:

```
    TM_MFRC522_Status_t TM_MFRC522_Auth(uint8_t authMode, uint8_t BlockAddr, uint8_t* Sectorkey, uint8_t* serNum) {
    TM_MFRC522_Status_t status;
    uint16_t recvBits;
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t buff[12];

    //Verify the command block address + sector + password + card serial number
    buff[0] = authMode;
    buff[1] = BlockAddr;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        buff[i+2] = Sectorkey[i];
    }
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        buff[i+8] = serNum[i];
    }
    status = TM_MFRC522_ToCard(PCD_AUTHENT, buff, 12, buff, &recvBits);

    if ((status != MI_OK) || (!(TM_MFRC522_ReadRegister(MFRC522_REG_STATUS2) & 0x08))) {
        status = MI_ERR;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work" Can you be more specific? Which function failed?

Answer (score 1):

It is common that producer of RFID card uses 6 bytes of 0xFF or 0x00 as default key of the product.

I have not used these libraries as with rc522 but try to pass this

char keyA[6] = { 0xFF, 0xFf, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, };
to authenticate.

Note that if you write something else in pass sectors you have corrupted the card.